# Accessing database with sqlite in Java

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite, database-connection

I am trying to access a database to then insert new data, but the code below gives me this output:

```
Opened database successfully
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database ()
```

The database is created in a different class, I still get this error whether the database has already been created or not.
What would be causing this error?

```
    Statement stmt = null;
    Connection c = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/test.db");
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

        stmt = c.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO table_one (id, name) VALUES (Null, 'Hayley');";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql); 
        System.out.println("Inserted records");

        stmt.close();
        c.close();

    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }
System.out.println("Table created sucessfully");
```

Comment: database really exist ?

Comment: Don't create content in your `src` directory, it won't exist at run time...

Comment: Didn't know that so changed the directory, still have same error however

Comment: Does the table `table_one` exist in the database file?

Comment: yes table_one does exist in the database file, the same error still occurs if I try to add data in the same class as where this database is created

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM table_one`. If that fails, you have not opened the correct database file.

Answer (score 0):

How about not inserting the `null` value in the `id` column. It is of no use to insert `null` value. It might have generated the sql exception. Try `INSERT INTO table_one (name) VALUES ('Hayley');`.

I would suggest to use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` because of the threat of SQL injection.

Sometimes, the particular sql exception can occur if the database name is not given. Have you tried writing the database name like `INSERT INTO database_name.table_one (name) VALUES ('Hayley');`.

Comment: Gives this error `java.sql.SQLException: not supported by PreparedStatment` What would cause that?

Comment: Inserting NULL into an [autoincrementing column](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) is perfectly fine. As long as there are no attached databases, database names are never needed.